# How to Return Only Selected API Parameters in Python

Tags: python, api, parameters

how can i return or select only those parameters that are needed in Python dict format. Not all of the parameters that are being return.

Here is the url we use:
[https://api.nytimes.com/svc/search/v2/articlesearch.json?begin_date=20201020&facet=false&sort=newest&api-key=[YOUR_API_KEY]](https://api.nytimes.com/svc/search/v2/articlesearch.json?begin_date=20201020&facet=false&sort=newest&api-key=%5BYOUR_API_KEY%5D)

Here is the response we get:

```
{
  "status": "OK",
  "copyright": "Copyright (c) 2020 The New York Times Company. All Rights Reserved.",
  "response": {
    "docs": [
      {
        "abstract": "Our latest survey shows a shift toward Biden among college-educated white voters, but surprising Trump gains among nonwhite voters.",
        "web_url": "https://www.nytimes.com/2020/10/20/upshot/poll-georgia-biden-trump.html",
        "snippet": "Our latest survey shows a shift toward Biden among college-educated white voters, but surprising Trump gains among nonwhite voters.",
        "lead_paragraph": "A shift against President Trump among white college-educated voters in Georgia has imperiled Republicans up and down the ballot, according to a New York Times/Siena College survey on Tuesday, as Republicans find themselves deadlocked or trailing in Senate races where their party was once considered the heavy favorite.",
        "source": "The New York Times",
        "multimedia": [
          {
            "rank": 0,
            "subtype": "xlarge",
            "caption": null,
            "credit": null,
            "type": "image",
            "url": "images/2020/10/20/us/undefined-promo-1603200878027/undefined-promo-1603200878027-articleLarge.jpg",
            "height": 399,
            "width": 600,
            "legacy": {
              "xlarge": "images/2020/10/20/us/undefined-promo-1603200878027/undefined-promo-1603200878027-articleLarge.jpg",
              "xlargewidth": 600,
              "xlargeheight": 399
            },
            "subType": "xlarge",
            "crop_name": "articleLarge"
          },
..........
```

How can i only return for example:
web_url and source parameters in Python?

Please help !!!

this is the code i use, but it returns all parameters:

```
    import requests
    import os
    from pprint import pprint

    apikey = os.getenv('VGSDRL9bWiWy70GdCPA4QX8flAsemVGJ', '...')
    query_url = "https://api.nytimes.com/svc/search/v2/articlesearch.json?q=trump&sort=newest&api-key=VGSDRL9bWiWy70GdCPA4QX8flAsemVGJ"
    r = requests.get(query_url)    
    pprint(r.json())
```

Answer (score 0):

```
r = requests.get(query_url)
filtered = [{'web_url': d['web_url'], 'source': d['source']} for d in
            r.json()['response']['docs']]
pprint(filtered)
```